# type template for derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, typename

```
template <typename ElementType>
class AList{};
class A{};
class B : public A{};
class C : public A{};
class D : public A{};
template <typename TypeE>
class E{};
(...)
       AList< E<A> > ListofEwithBCandDasTypE;
```

However the displayed code only makes a list of E with A as template argument. How can I solve that?

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: a list of E with class B, C and D as template argument

Comment: `AList< E<B> > listB` ? Maybe you want to have a list with different types in the same list ?

Comment: a yes but these different types are all derived from A as Baseclass.

Comment: `AList< E<A*> > alist;`

Comment: @AntonSavin I try that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++98 (I'm not comfortable with C++11).

You need polymorphism and manage pointers instead of objects directly. See this example :

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};
class B : public A
{
  public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};
class C : public A
{
  public:
    virtual ~C() {}
};
template <typename T>
class AList
{
  public:
    add(T* x);
    // ...
};
template <typename T>
class E
{
  public:
    E(A* ptr) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};
AList< E<A*> > list;
list.add(E(new B));
list.add(E(new C));
```

Don't forget to manage your memory !